# How to "catch" concern using Aspect Oriented Programming in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter

AOP suggest an implementation of loging and validating aspects of a class to meet business logic.
[This article](http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/aop/intro-to-aspect-oriented-programming) shows an example of implementing "around" / "wrap" method of AOP in javascript to validate the value of object's attribute.
http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/aop/intro-to-aspect-oriented-programming

**I would like to know the implementation of a "catch" using AOP approach with javascript.**

Let say we have a class `Thing` that have multiple methods altering an attribute `.location`.  Instances of `Thing` has been created all across the app and the `.location` attribute may have set to `"went missing"` undetected.

One aspect I would like to take care now is the attribute `.location`.  `.location` can be set to any value but cannot `"went missing"`.  Not at any moment, any instance of `Thing` should set it's `.location` to `"went missing"`.

I would like to trigger a `catch` when any instance set it's `.location` to `"went missing"`. Upon catching, I should be able to trace which method and which instance triggers it allowing `Thing` to handle it's instance accordingly.

Much like catching errors with `try-catch`, where we can catch error event and handle it accordingly.

```
function Thing(){
    this.location = "in the safe box";
    this.move = function(str){
        this.location = str;
    },
    this.walk = function(str){
        this.location = str;
    },
    this.run = function(str){
        this.location = str;
    }
}

var myBook = new Thing();
var yourBook = new Thing();
var hisBook = new Thing();

var book = [myBook,yourBook,hisBook];

var cycle = 0;

startTimer(function(){
    // randomly select which instance and which action
    var instance = book[Math.floor(Math.random() * book.length)];
    var action = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var location = ( Math.random()%5 == 0 )? "went missing" : "some where else";

    if( action == 1 ) instance.move(location);
    else if( action == 2 ) instance.walk(location);
    else if( action == 3 ) instance.run(location);

    cycle += 1;

},10000);
```

How do we catch when a book `.location = "went missing"` ? I would like to stop the move operation when a book `.location` detected "went missing" and reset it's `.location` to `"in the safe box"`.  I should also be able to trace which book, by which method on which cycle.

**What is your approach upon finding every instance of `Thing` that "went missing"?**

Comment: Yes, you can use `try/catch` with `wrap`. Have you tried it?

Comment: WTH do you mean by "went missing", what does it have to do with exceptions? And why do you assign to a global variable three times in a row?

Comment: I have edit the sample code.

Comment: I still don't see what this has to do with AOP. Sounds like you are looking for a setter method/property.

Comment: What is your approach upon finding every instance of `Thing` that use method `move` and "went missing"?

Comment: What do you mean by "finding"? What's the expected result? How would you do this without AOP?

Comment: I have further clarify my example. This is a sample case of what actually happens in an application. If we have a class of `Thing`. We would like to capture every instance of it that have set its `.location` to "went missing" which violates our business logic. We would want to capture, then handle it or just log it and analize the cause of such behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Add a setter (/getter) that validates your state:

```
Object.defineProperty(Thint.prototype, "location", {
    get: function() {
        return this._location
    },
    set: function(val) {
        if (!/^on the/.test(val)) // or val == "went missing" or whatever
            throw new Error("invalid value for .location"); // or fix it or log it etc
        this._location = val;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```